# How to plot an arrary of .pngs with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose you have some `i-1` images in some folder. How can I make this code render them in some grid with number of columns `int((i-1)**0.5)` (as this would make a square of images)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mplimg
import pylab
import numpy as np

for j in range(i):
   image=mplimg.imread("c:\\users\\laurence\\dropbox\\ggl\\images\\"+str(j)+".png")
   arr=np.asarray(image)
```

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but here's the general idea.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import numpy as np

# glob won't preserve the order that the files are in (if you need that, you can
# simply do what you were already doing. Globbing is simpler, though.
filenames = glob.glob('c:/path/to/your/photos/*.png')
# Forward slashes work for pathnames on windows, too (at least in python)

# Let's not assume that there's an exact square number of images
nrows = np.ceil(np.sqrt(len(filenames))).astype(int)
ncols = len(filenames) // nrows

# Subplots returns a figure and a _2d array_ of axes in a grid.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

# Note that we're iterating over ``axes.flat``, not just axes (which is 2d)
for filename, ax in zip(filenames, axes.flat):
    data = plt.imread(filename)
    ax.imshow(data)

    # You might want to hide the labels, border, etc
    ax.axis('off')

# Not necessary, but this will give you more evenly located subplots
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Many thanks for this response, however when I this I receive:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'suplots'

Comment: Typo on my part. Should have been `subplots`.

Comment: Ok, so my matplotlib doesn't seem to have a module subplot.. not sure why! Everything else seems great though!

Comment: I just had a lot of thoughtless typos in my original version.  I had imported `matplotlib as plt` instead of `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  I've fixed several similar typos, and the example should work as-is. Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem at all! Very good of you to go through this with me. I'm currently trying to debug it, here is the error I am now getting:
`__main__:35: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars
...
IndexError: index out of range`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback somewhere? (a link to a pastebin is fine) I'm a bit stumped by the portion of it you posted...

Comment: Many thanks, I changed "fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)", not sure if this was correct, but seemed to fix the error, seem to get this error now http://pastebin.com/TSuKccjP